# Как сделать рандомное перемешивание строк в DataTable?

Tags: c#, mysql

Необходимо реализовать функцию для перемешивания строк в таблице DataTable. Как это сделать?

Comment: А откуда в ней строки появляются?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108819/best-way-to-randomize-an-array-with-net

Comment: @АндрейNOP я из бд получаю. Сейчас думаю может лучше будет сделать на стороне бд перемешивание и отправку в datatable

Comment: Да, в запросе напишите `ORDER BY RAND()`

Comment: Просто DataTable не лучшее место для перемешивания, если хотите перемешивать на стороне клиента, то лучше читайте данные из БД в коллекцию и перемешивайте в ней.

Comment: @АндрейNOP RAND() вернет одинаковое число для всех строк. Нужно вызвать NEWID()

Comment: Order by rand - убийство производительности, неоднократно [обсуждалось](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=ORDER%20BY%20rand%20site%3Ahabr.com&lr=213&clid=2186621) на хабре.

Comment: Вопрос не относится к c#, поправьте метки вопроса и укажите что у вас за база.

Comment: @iluxa1810, да ладно, у меня oracle и не знаю я ни про какую `newid()`

Comment: @AK, как это не относится? Изначально вопрос про то как переставить строки в DataTable. Это уже наши додумки, что ему может лучше сортировать на стороне БД. Но тут ведь зависит от задачи и может и не лучше...

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ну в MS SQL через NEWID только делать такое...

Comment: @iluxa1810, а у автора MS SQL?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, не знаю...

Comment: @AK, ну и про то что `ORDER BY RAND()` убийство производительности тоже спорно, потому что мы не знаем реальной задачи. Если вы сортируете всю коллекцию ради того, чтобы потом сверху у нее взять максимальный элемент — да, оверхед. Но если вам нужны ВСЕ элементы переставленные в случайном порядке, то никакого оверхерда не будет.

Comment: Автор, уточните, где именно вы хотите сделать перемешивание: в БД (тогда уберите метку C#, поставьте метку sql) или именно в DataTable (тогда метку СУБД нужно убрать). Для первого случая варианты уже привели. Для второго случая вбейте в любой поисковик запрос "array shuffle". См. [Knuth shuffle](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle)

Answer (score 0):

Решил сделать решение данной проблемы на стороне бд (MYSQL). Сделал с помощью Rand()